# Analyzing nginx webserver logs to detect DDOS attack

Tags: log-files, ddos

I recently experienced a DDoS attack. How do I analyze nginx webserver logs from that time window to detect [what kind](https://www.rivalhost.com/12-types-of-ddos-attacks-used-by-hackers) of DDoS it was? I'm using Microsoft Azure infrastructure (in case it matters).

I understand that log analysis tools like [Loggly](http://loggly.com) can be used. But I can't upload log files to that in order to analyze them - I need to instead connect the service to my live server and it gives me an analysis dashboard to use.

Comment: @EEAA: thanks for chiming in. I'm actually a newbie sysadmin and just finding my away around learning the ropes. A web application my startup maintains recently got DDoS'd, and I'm trying to figure out the why, what and how. Could you explain which one would show up in my nginx logs, and why?

Comment: I just turned my comments into an answer. :)

Comment: Thank you for helping me out! Could you point me toward what kind of measures I can take to prep for the next time? And should I talk to someone in Microsoft Azure's team to help me out later? I was also thinking I'd set up CloudFlare, but I have a substantial number of non-JS users too, and CloudFlare doesn't cover that.

Comment: DDoS prevention is a very deep subject, much too deep to deal with properly here. Yes, you should talk with Azure about this. They may have some DDoS protection that they can offer you, or at the very least, make recommendations as to how you might deploy your application so that it's more resistant to these attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, only one of those types would even show up in your Nginx logs.

First, if it's a true DDoS, you likely have zero ability to do anything about it. Once the traffic hits your server, even if it's blocked at a firewall or throttled in your webserver, the traffic is already consuming your network bandwidth, and you can do nothing about it. Thus, it needs to be blocked "upstream", in the routing gear servicing your server.

To answer your question (from your comment), your webserver is an "application", running at OSI layer 7. It logs http-level things but knows nothing about the network layers below 7. In your list of DDoS types, all of the rest other than "application level attacks" happen at lower levels of your network stack than nginx, so you'll need to look elsewhere for information on those type of attacks.

It's likely that there are no logs on your server that will give you any indication to the nature of the attack unless you'd previously configured such logs in advance of the attack. Right now, the best you can do is prepare for the next time it happens, to ensure you have the right tools in your toolbox, and that your network provider is ready to mitigate from their end.

Comment: Would you also be able to put in an addendum on what measure of preparation goes behind mounting a DDoS attack? I'm trying to assess whether, or how soon, our attackers will be back (or how much time we possibly have before the next event).